Understanding the (integer)$ p$-adic numbers and its canonical embedding
I did learn the following:

The integer p-adic numbers are defined as
$\mathbb{Z}_p:=\{(\overline{x_k}) \in \prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$
/ $p^{k+1}\mathbb{Z}:x_{k+1} \equiv x_k \mod p^{k+1}\}$ for $p$ prime.
We have the canonical map $\epsilon_p: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow
> \mathbb{Z}_p, x \mapsto \overline{x}_{k \in \mathbb{N_0}}
> =(\overline{x},\overline{x},\overline{x},...)$

Now I want to understand the above definition.
As far as I can see, by using $\epsilon_p$ one can write a number $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ in its $p$-adic representation.
So for example consider $p=7$.
Then $\epsilon_7(173)=(\overline{173},\overline{173},\overline{173},...)$.
One the other hand, the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ states that $x_{k+1}\equiv x_k \mod 7^{k+1}$.
And I would like to calculate $x_0,x_1,x_2,...$ etc.
Since $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, I get $173 \equiv 5 \mod 7$.
Then for $x_1 \in \mathbb{Z}/7^2\mathbb{Z}$, I get $173 \equiv 26 \mod 7^2$.
For $x_2$, $173 \equiv 173 \mod 7^3$ and thus for all following indices.
Thus I get $\epsilon_7(173)=(\overline{173},\overline{173},\overline{173},...)=(\overline{5},\overline{26},\overline{173},\overline{173},...)$.
I am not sure if my calculation is correct, since
in calculating $(\overline{5},\overline{26},\overline{173},\overline{173},...)$ I did use that $x_j \in \mathbb{Z}/7^j \mathbb{Z}$ but I didn't use $x_{k+1} \equiv x_k \mod p^{k+1}$.

@CJDowd Maybe make that an answer.

That condition comes for free for any integer: considering an integer mod $p^k$ is the same as considering it mod $p^{k + 1}$ and then reducing that further modulo $p^k$. The point of the compatibility condition is that you get new $p$-adic integers, not just those coming from rational integers. The compatibility condition guarantees that $p$-adic integers "look like" integers when you study them modulo $p^k$ for any finite $k$, but as you consider all the reductions as $k \to \infty$ you can obtain something that does not come from an integer.

Moved this from a comment to an answer.
